# Last day of current quarter date parameter SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'd like some of my SSRS reports to default to show the dates of the current financial quarter when they run.

I'm in the UK so Quarter 1 = `01-APR-2018` to `30-JUN-2018`   etc

I have two date parameters (SSRS). For the first parameter I've used this expression:

```
=DateAdd(DateInterval.Quarter, DateDiff(DateInterval.Quarter, CDate("1/1/1900"), Today()), CDate("1/1/1900"))
```

When I run the report, it defaults to `01-APR-2018`, which is what I want.

However, I've been unable to work out an expression to bring through the final day of the current quarter.

Any ideas of how to achieve this would be appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question plus the T-SQL. This is very helpful.

Comment: No worries mate :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### SSRS Expression

Here's the expression that will work in your report.

#### Last Day of Current Quarter

```
= DATEADD(
   DateInterval.Day
   , -1
   , DATEADD(
      DateInterval.Quarter
      , DATEPART(DateInterval.Quarter, DateTime.Now )
      , DATESERIAL(YEAR(Now), 1, 1)   
   )
)
```

### T-SQL Examples

Here are the formulas in SQL, if you want to drive the defaults from a query. This way you can create a view on the database and use that instead of having to do the expressions in your report. If you don't have permissions to create the view, you can create a `Shared Dataset` / `.rsd` file on the report server using just the select statement.

#### First Day of Current Quarter

```
SELECT [first_quarter_day] = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

#### Last Day of Current Quarter

```
SELECT [last_quarter_day] = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, 1 ,DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
```

[image: query results]

### View Example

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[date_defaults]
AS

    SELECT 
      [First_Day_of_Current_Month] = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0, GETDATE()), 0)
    , [Last_Day_of_Current_Month] = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
    , [First_Day_of_Next_Month] = DATEADD(mm, 1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    , [Last_Day_of_Previous_Month] = DATEADD(dd, -1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    , [First_Day_of_Current_Quarter] = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    , [First_Day_of_Previous_Quarter] = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
    , [Last_Day_of_Current_Quarter] = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, 1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
    , [Last_Day_of_Previous_Quarter] = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    , [First_Day_of_Current_Year] = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0, GETDATE()), 0)
    , [First_Day_of_Previous_Year] = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0,DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())), 0)
    , [Last_Day_of_Previous_Year] = DATEADD(dd, -1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    , [This_Day_Last_Year]  = DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())

GO
```

### Shared Dataset XML example

Note: You'll have to update the `DataSourceReference` with a datasource on the report server.

[image: ssrs project]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SharedDataSet xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2010/01/shareddatasetdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <DataSet Name="date_defaults">
    <Query>
      <DataSourceReference>Your_DataSource_Here</DataSourceReference>
      <CommandText> SELECT 
      [First_Day_of_Current_Month] = DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0, GETDATE()), 0)
    , [Last_Day_of_Current_Month] = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(mm, 1, DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
    , [First_Day_of_Next_Month] = DATEADD(mm, 1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    , [Last_Day_of_Previous_Month] = DATEADD(dd, -1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    , [First_Day_of_Current_Quarter] = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    , [First_Day_of_Previous_Quarter] = DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE())-1, 0)
    , [Last_Day_of_Current_Quarter] = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, 1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0)))
    , [Last_Day_of_Previous_Quarter] = DATEADD(dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    , [First_Day_of_Current_Year] = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0, GETDATE()), 0)
    , [First_Day_of_Previous_Year] = DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0,DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())), 0)
    , [Last_Day_of_Previous_Year] = DATEADD(dd, -1,DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
    , [This_Day_Last_Year]  = DATEADD(yy, -1, GETDATE())</CommandText>
    </Query>
    <Fields>
      <Field Name="First_Day_of_Current_Month">
        <DataField>First_Day_of_Current_Month</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="Last_Day_of_Current_Month">
        <DataField>Last_Day_of_Current_Month</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="First_Day_of_Next_Month">
        <DataField>First_Day_of_Next_Month</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="Last_Day_of_Previous_Month">
        <DataField>Last_Day_of_Previous_Month</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="First_Day_of_Current_Quarter">
        <DataField>First_Day_of_Current_Quarter</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="First_Day_of_Previous_Quarter">
        <DataField>First_Day_of_Previous_Quarter</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="Last_Day_of_Current_Quarter">
        <DataField>Last_Day_of_Current_Quarter</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="Last_Day_of_Previous_Quarter">
        <DataField>Last_Day_of_Previous_Quarter</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="First_Day_of_Current_Year">
        <DataField>First_Day_of_Current_Year</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="First_Day_of_Previous_Year">
        <DataField>First_Day_of_Previous_Year</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="Last_Day_of_Previous_Year">
        <DataField>Last_Day_of_Previous_Year</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
      <Field Name="This_Day_Last_Year">
        <DataField>This_Day_Last_Year</DataField>
        <rd:TypeName>System.DateTime</rd:TypeName>
      </Field>
    </Fields>
  </DataSet>
</SharedDataSet>
```

Comment: `DATESERIAL` can also handle negative values, which would make your Last Day of Current Quarter code shorter: `DATESERIAL(YEAR(Now), 1, -1)`. Then you have one `DATEADD` less,